# Disabling Outlook Shared Folders via PS

Tags: powershell, outlook, registry, system-administration

I am running into an issue with my powershell script.
The purpose is to disable outlook shared folders downloading. (This is for performance related issues) Yes, I know I could do it with GPO (even though this doesnt really work) but I want to be able to run a powershell script that does it. I have isolated the registry values that I think need to change. (See below) But when I change the value it is not reflected in outlook. I am thinking that it might be due to hashing in the registry. Not sure. I had an script I used to change the registry to make PDFs open in adobe acrobat and it used hashing.

Registry path: HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\cached mode
Key: CacheOthersMail

Helpful Information:
Outlook Shared folders: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/data-files/by-default-shared-mail-folders-are-downloaded-in-cashed

Adobe PDF script: https://github.com/DanysysTeam/PS-SFTA/blob/master/SFTA.ps1

Command I tried:
`New-ItemProperty -Path “HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\cached mode” -Name CacheOthersMail -Value 0 -PropertyType DWORD -Force`

Comment: Both your links are broken and point to https://stackoverflow.com